# javascriptでfor文をつかい何人かの生徒の中から最高得点の人の名前を出したい

Tags: javascript

こういう場合どういったコードを書けば良いのでしょう？
教材を確認したのですが理解できず困っています。

> 以下のような生徒の情報があります。
>
> この中で一番高得点のユーザーの名前だけを出力してください。
> ただし、for文を使って比較すること。

```
const students = [
  { name: "田中太郎", score: 33 },
  { name: "山田花子", score: 20 },
  { name: "鈴木次郎", score: 94 },
  { name: "佐藤三郎", score: 40 },
  { name: "山本四郎", score: 50 },
  { name: "松本五郎", score: 60 },
  { name: "中田六郎", score: 70 },
  { name: "小林七郎", score: 22 },
  { name: "加藤八郎", score: 44 },
  { name: "伊藤九郎", score: 67 },
];
```

Comment: 教材のカバー範囲やあなたの理解度が分からないと、どこからどこまで回答すべきかが分からないです。 / 「どんな手続きをすべきか箇条書きで説明できる」「単純な2つの点数の比較ならできる」「for文の使い方は分かる」など、どこまで理解していてどこからわからないかを明確にしてみてください。

Comment: わざわざご回答ありがとうございます！！

Comment: 「教材を確認したのですが理解できず困っています。」とのことですが、その教材の説明はどのようなものでどの箇所が分からなかったのでしょうか？具体的に書かれると何かアドバイスできることがあるかもしれません。

Comment: 本日別の教材で複数人の点数を合計して平均点を割り出すところをやったところです！！

Comment: 言葉足らずですいません！　本日講師の方から宿題を出されたのですが　一応そこのスクール？の教材を色々確認してたのですが、一番得点の高いひとを出すコードとその人の名前を出すコードがわからなくて質問しました。

Answer (score 0):

※ 同点一位はない、という前提です。

```js
const students = [
  { name: "田中太郎", score: 33 },
  { name: "山田花子", score: 20 },
  { name: "鈴木次郎", score: 94 },
  { name: "佐藤三郎", score: 40 },
  { name: "山本四郎", score: 50 },
  { name: "松本五郎", score: 60 },
  { name: "中田六郎", score: 70 },
  { name: "小林七郎", score: 22 },
  { name: "加藤八郎", score: 44 },
  { name: "伊藤九郎", score: 67 },
];

var best_score = 0;
var best_student = "";
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  if (students[i]['score'] > best_score) {
    best_score = students[i]['score'];
    best_student = students[i]['name'];
  }
}

console.log(best_student)
```

#### オマケ

> ただし、for文を使って比較すること。

以下、`for`文ではなく、`reduce` を使う場合。

```js
const best_student = students.reduce((a, b) => a.score > b.score ? a : b).name;
console.log(best_student)
```

Comment: わざわざご丁寧にありがとうございます！助かりました！！

Answer (score 0):

> この中で一番高得点のユーザーの名前だけを出力してください。
> ただし、for文を使って比較すること。

最高点と比較するという意味なら, 以下もアリ？
(同一高得点の場合も表示可能)

```js
const students = [
    { name: "田中太郎", score: 33 },
    { name: "山田花子", score: 20 },
    { name: "鈴木次郎", score: 94 },
    { name: "佐藤三郎", score: 40 },
    { name: "山本四郎", score: 50 },
    { name: "松本五郎", score: 60 },
    { name: "中田六郎", score: 70 },
    { name: "小林七郎", score: 22 },
    { name: "加藤八郎", score: 44 },
    { name: "伊藤九郎", score: 67 },
];

let maxval = Math.max(...students.map(a => a.score))
for ({name, score} of students) {
    if (score == maxval) {
        console.log(name)
    }
}
```